# How do you retrieve the list of enums?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I ran into this and wanted to post it for others:

When you have a model like this:

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: [ :active, :archived ]
end
```

How do you get the list of available "statuses" (enums) within the application?

Answer (score 1):

I didnt see it in the documentation, but it is just the plural version of the enum. So in the example above:

```
Conversation.statuses      # {"active"=>0, "archived"=>1}
Conversation.statuses.keys # ["active", "archived"]
```

Comment: [You should read the documentation carefully.](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html). _In rare circumstances you might need to access the mapping directly. The mappings are exposed through a class method with the **pluralized** attribute name, which return the mapping in a HashWithIndifferentAccess_

Comment: Is this still true? I tried this on a Rails 5.2 app on Ruby 2.4 and my `account_type` attribute had no pluralized version. Is there any other way to access it?

Comment: @Bradley yes this is still true on Rails 5.2. You should be able to call MyClassName.account_types to get a list.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I missed that it was a class method and not an instance method and I was trying to access it from another instance method. I ended up using a `self.class.statuses` and it worked great. Thanks again!!